# ERROR. LiveLiteralKt Not found! in the Event Logs

Tags: android, android-studio

I've updated my Android Studio to *Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1*. After that, strange errors began to appear in the logs: `[ERROR] LiveLiteralKt Not found!`Previously, there were no such errors. Has anyone encountered this? Do you know how to fix this? Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I too caught this in Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 !! [ERROR] LiveLiteralKt Not found! I think that must be caught during debugging phases...

Comment: I am receiving `[ERROR] LiveLiteralKt Not found!` on **Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1**.

Comment: I am receiving `[ERROR] LiveLiteralKt Not found!` whenever I have a syntax error on **Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1**

Answer (score 2):

Try to update your NDK and CMAKE with the SDK Manager.

I was using some native code in my app and was getting this error too. After updating NDK and CMAKE the error never appeared anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have also got this error. I have fixed this error by changing in

**gradle-wrapper.properties  and updated latest distributionUrl**

[image: Gradle wrapper class you may find in project directory]

Also Please make sure that in signed apk .jks file and all other credential like alias name, store key password is same if you are making signed apk for existing build available on play console.

Comment: The error cropped up having latest URL specified (gradle 7.3.3)